# attempting to convert String data into numerical data, the drop the data into an array of arrays (Json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this:

```
    (65.94647177615738, 87.890625)(47.040182144806664, 90)(45.089035564831036, 122.34375)
```

I'm attempting to get the output to look like this:

```
   "coords": [[65.94647177615738, 87.890625],[47.040182144806664, 90],[45.089035564831036, 122.34375]]
```

Any Idea?

The first result comes back to me as a string, so when i try to assign the first object to an array, the console shows me this:

```
  array is:  "(65.94647177615738, 87.890625)(47.040182144806664, 90)(45.089035564831036, 122.34375)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "(65.94647177615738, 87.890625)(47.040182144806664, 90)(45.089035564831036, 122.34375)";
str = str.slice(1,-1); // remove outermost parentheses
var arrCoord = str.split(')(');  
for (var i=0; i<arrCoord.length; i++) {
    var tarr = arrCoord[i].split(", ");
    for (var j=0; j<tarr.length; j++) {
        tarr[j] = parseFloat(tarr[j]);
    }
    arrCoord[i] = tarr;
}
// arrCoord is now populated with arrays of numbers
```

Comment: tee hee, I'd split those too =]

Comment: You sir, are a magnificent stud! Works perfectly!  I got almost all of that earlier, but couldn't quite figure out how to slice off the outermost parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to sort of play code golf.  Assuming:

```
var sample = '(65.94647177615738, 87.890625)(47.040182144806664, 90)(45.089035564831036, 122.34375)';
```

Then:

```
var coords = sample
    .split(/\(([^)]+)\)/)
    .filter(function(v){return v!=""})
    .map(function(v){return v.split(/[^0-9\.]+/)})
```